# Getting the Error "make: *** No rule to make target `ins-all'. Stop." when trying to compile GNAT with the help of the "doinstall" file

Tags: unix, makefile, gnat

i am trying to install the Ada-Compiler GNAT on my Unix system.

When i execute the "doinstall" file and pasted in my installation path i get this an error, which i can't desolve atm.

Did one of you already walk by this error in combination with gnat and unix and has an idea how to solve it?

"make: *** No rule to make target `ins-all'.  Stop."

Comment: What kind of Unix is this, Linux, BSD or something else? I think that GNAT requires a GNU Make and your error message reminds me a message I have on FreeBSD when using BSD Make on GNU Make makefile.

Comment: Hi, 
i am trying to figure it out on a CentOS 7 -> a Red Hat Enterprise Linux. 

I just checked it: My "make" is the classic "GNU make".